# "lerp" returning value (Shader)?

Tags: unity, shaders, lerp

I don't understand the `lerp` example in this code :

```
if(dot(WorldNormalVector(IN, o.Normal), _SnowDirection.xyz)>=lerp(1,-1,_Snow))
                o.Albedo = _SnowColor.rgb;
            else
```

(Snow is in the range 0..1)

The article says :
We then compare the dot value with a lerp - if our Snow level is 0 (no snow) this returns 1 and if the Snow level is 1 it will return -1 (the entire rock is covered).  It's quite normal to only vary the snow level between 0..0.5 when we use this shader so that we only have snow on surfaces that actually face the snow direction.

Why does it return 1 (with Snow at 0) and -1 (with Snow at 1) ?

(source: http://unitygems.com/noobs-guide-shaders-2/ )

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about the definition of the `lerp` function?  If so, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509618.aspx

Comment: @NathanReed Thanks, actually I don't understand it, why using "lerp" (an interpolation..?) to compare _Snow with the dot product? What does actually return lerp here: a different number between the frames? Or the same number, in this case, why not just put _Snow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_Snow` is in the range 0 to 1.  The dot product returns a value from -1 to 1.  The `lerp` is being used to convert `_Snow` to the -1 to 1 range for comparison with the dot product.  When `_Snow` is zero, no snow is desired, so the comparison becomes "dot product >= 1", which will never be true (well, except at points exactly facing the snow direction).  Conversely, when `_Snow` is 1, the comparison becomes "dot product >= -1", which will always be true, so you'll get snow everywhere.  Intermediate values of `_Snow` should generate intermediate values to compare the dot product against, hence the interpolation.

Comment: Supplemental: lerp(1, -1, _Snow) == (1 - (_Snow * 2))